# Possible unity memory leak

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I am learning a car to park itself using the ML framework from unity. I have some problems with unity crashing but my question is based on a potential memory leak.On the first screenshot,We are able to see how much of the memory goes to this process that I have opened. My code is a bit longer for a repost here but I can give you further shots if required.Has anyone experienced something similar before and would you have any ideas about the problem. In my code I keep a list of 4 colliders but I highly doubt it is the source of the problem. It wouldn't reach 8GB no matter what.
[First photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSRE.png)

[Second Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUexu.png)

EDIT: Placing some pictures of the code since it is a bit longer.

[Code Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYByQ.png)

[Code Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHFRt.png)

[Code Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFWX2.png)

[Code Part 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk77u.png)

[Code Part 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z42hh.png)

Comment: Try closing and relaunching unity. There are a few things that hangs in the background forever and a restart once in a while helps. Now if unity is still pulling 8gig with just your game running we'll need to see some code :D.

Comment: Restarting the Unity didn't help . I am trying to fix it from yesterday. I shall post my code

Comment: Hard to tell for us without having any code or your project in front of us ... can be come from anywhere ... large arrays that get allocated and never deleted ... large assets in your project ... e.g. Textures that get created but never destroyed ... resources that a loaded but never unloaded .. or actually thousands of objects created in your scene ^^ ... Your best option for now is to use the [**Profiler**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and watch frame by frame where memory usage raises and find out why this might be the case

Comment: I've placed the code in pictures since it would be too long I believe. If you are curious you can check them out :)

Comment: OnTriggerStay gets called every frame the colliders are touching and start a new Coroutine every frame. Check with a quick debug.log but it looks like it :). Seems like maybe you wanted to use Ontrigger(Enter) with your OntriggerExit?

Comment: I will definitely check this !!! But the answer is no , I want ontriggerStay . It is parking a car and I need it to be touching 4 colliders for a "good" parking visual. Thank you . I will simply try to put a check if the coroutine is started and if it is i will simply pass. Thanks for this answer I will try it and tell you if it worked. Good night for now guys !

Comment: Morning ! I have added a check to insure the coroutine is started just once from the agent. Still I get the same behaviour .

Comment: EDIT* I've just started one of their examples for 30minutes it took 2GB of memory. It is an issue within the Unity ML Library.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: What about it ? This is exactly machine learning , molddnilo

Comment: @IvailoManolov you should have read before answering... the ml tag is not about machine learning. BTW, your code isn't long and there is no reason whatsoever to post code as image around here. If you format your code properly, you'll see that it is not long, although I believe you can shorten it further by removing unnecessary parts.

Comment: Any ideas on the actual problem though ? Why do we have to focus on that ?

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days I can say for sure that Unity has a serious memory leak in their current ML library.For the people who will stumble upon this thread in the near future , Unity ML 2.0.0 at this time (7/19/2021) has a memory leak. It can result in (FPS dropping,Unity Timeout errors, Unity crashing in general). If you experience similar outcomes, open the memory profiler and let it run for a couple of minutes. You will see the memory increasing linearly. You can dump the memory and see which objects are created excessively.What I did was simply downgrading to ML 1.7.0 Lib.Be careful when setting up the project and don't forget to read the documentation. I hope this is helpful to someone. Have a great day :)